# How to go back to the first ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have several views. Here's what it looks like: First view is StartViewController (arrow), which opens TabBarController which is owner of two other views - FavoriteViewController and MapViewController. How to close all of them and go back to the StartViewController?
This should work like starting the app from first view.
I found similar question, but unfortunately it doesn't work.
[How to go back to the initial ViewController the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197385/how-to-go-back-to-the-initial-viewcontroller-the-right-way)

[image]

Comment: *"... StartViewController (arrow), which opens TabBarController ..."* -- first question: what do you mean by "opens"? Do you *present* the TabBarController? If so, you can *dismiss* it. Second question: ***why*** do you want to do that? It sounds like it could really confuse the user, and users don't like having to "figure out" different navigation in every app they use.

Comment: I tried dismiss but it works different. Dismiss starts the first ViewController in the navigation stack, not the initial VC. So it gives me a blank view. In the first VC app downloads the data. It's more convenient and takes less code.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense... if `StartViewController` ***presents*** `TabBarController`, `StartViewController` can then ***dismiss*** it. Doesn't matter how deep you are into a navigation controller stack, or which tab you are on.

Comment: The word "present" here means something very specific: that you call `present(_:animated:completion:)` to display your view controller modally. Once you are done with a view controller you've displayed that way, you call `dismiss(animated:completion:)` to dismiss that modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** First dismiss your current viewController by `self.CurrentVC.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

**2.** then, present/show your first or intial viewController `present(firstVC,animated: true,completion: nil)`

Here **CurrentVC** is the name for your current viewController and **firstVC** will be the name of your first viewController that you want to show.